# Why won't JS / JQuery read the text box values?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have looked all over for a reason behind why this code does not work and I am stumped.

I have an ASPX page with C# code behind.  The HTML mark-up has a JQuery dialog that functions properly. When the submit button is clicked the dialog closes and the data is passed to a web exposed method and is written to the database.  All values are saved for the ddl and chkbox controls but the string value of the text box is empty.  The database is set to NOT NULL for the field the text box is populating and the data is being saved so I know data is being passed but it is not the value entered into the text box.

The text box ID is txtCategoryName and the Client ID mode is set to static. I have tried to get the values using the following:

```
var CategoryName = $('#txtCategoryName').val();
var CategoryName = $('#txtCategoryName').text();
var CategoryName = $(document.getElementById('txtCategoryName')).text();
var CategoryName = $(document.getElementById('txtCategoryName')).val();
var CategoryName = document.getElementById('txtCategoryName').value;
```

All of these return the same blank field.  I tried them one at a time.
Currently I am using this JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var CategoryDialog = $(".EditCategories");
var BtnNew = $("#btnNew");
var CatDDL = document.getElementById("ddlCategoryParent3");
var CatChk = $("#chkCatActive").val();
var CategoryID = 0;
var CategoryName = $("#txtCategoryName").val();
var ParentID = CatDDL.options[CatDDL.selectedIndex].value;
if (CatChk) { CatChk = 1; } else { CatChk = 0; }



var CatDialog = $(CategoryDialog.dialog({

    maxHeight: 1000,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    scrollable: false,
    width: 650,
    title: 'Category Editor',
    autoOpen: false,


    buttons: [
        {
            width: 170,
            text: "Save",
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-disk"
            },
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                window.alert(PageMethods.saveCat(CategoryName, ParentID, CategoryID, CatChk));

            }

        },

        {
            width: 170,
            text: "Delete",
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-circle-minus"
            },
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }

        },
        {
            width: 170,
            text: "Cancel",
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-circle-close"
            },
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }

        }
    ]
})






);



BtnNew.click(function () {
    $(CatDialog).dialog('open');
    $(CatDialog).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

});




});
```

The code markup for the aspx page (categories.aspx)

```
<div class="EditCategories">
    <div class="Table">
        <div class="TableRow">

                <div class="TableCell">
                           <div class="TextBlock220">Category Name </div>
                </div><!-- End Table Cell -->
                <div class="TableCell">
                    <input id="txtCategoryName" class="ControlTextBox" />
                    <!--<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryName" CssClass="ControlTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>-->
                 </div><!--End Table Cell-->
             </div><!-- End Row 1 -->
         <div class="TableRow">
               <div class="TableCell">
                           Parent Category
               </div><!-- End Table Cell -->
               <div class="TableCell">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategoryParent3" runat="server" CssClass="ControlDropDownList" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
               </div><!--End Table Cell-->
         </div>
         <div class="TableRow">
                    <div class="TableCell">
                          Active
                    </div><!-- End Table Cell -->
                    <div class="TableCell">
                          <asp:Checkbox ID="chkCatActive"      CssClass="ControlCheckBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Checkbox>
                    </div><!--End Table Cell-->
         </div><!-- End Row 3-->


        </div>
</div>
```

The C# Code behind method for the ASPX page:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static string saveCat(string _Name_, int _parent_id_, int ID, int _Status_)
{
    Category eCT = new Category();
    eCT.CategoryName = _Name_;
    eCT.ParentID = _parent_id_;
    eCT.ID = ID;
    eCT.Status = _Status_;
    eCT.Save();
    return eCT.resultMessage; 
}
```

And the save method:

```
/// <summary>
/// If the ID = 0 the data is written as a new category.
/// If the ID is greater than 0 the data is updated.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The objects result value will hold the result of the attempt to update data as type Boolean.  The objects resultMessage value will contain the string result of the attempt to add data.</returns>
public void Save()
{

    result = dl.CategoryExists(this);
    if (result) { resultMessage = "The parent category already contains a category named " + CategoryName.Trim(); }
    else { 
        if (ID > 0)
        {
            if (!result) { resultMessage = "There was an unexpected error updating " + CategoryName.Trim() + ". No changes were saved."; }
        }
        else
        {
            result = dl.InsertCategory(this);
            if (!result) { resultMessage = "There was an unexpected error creating the Category."; }
        }
    }
    if (result) { resultMessage = "New Category Successfully Created"; }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the values from your dialog at page startup time BEFORE they have been edited.

It looks like this:

```
var CategoryName = $("#txtCategoryName").val();
```

is run at page startup time before the page has been edited.  This will fetch the default value for the input field and will never reflect any editing that is done on the page.  The line of code above does not create a "live" connection with the input field on the page.  It just gets the value at the time that line of code is run and from then on there is no connection to any edits made to the field.

I would think you want to fetch the value only later when you actually need to value for something.  In general, you do not want to cache a value like this because the cached value gets out of sync with what is in the actual field on the page.  Just fetch it at the very moment that you need it for something and it will never have a stale value.

If the place that you're using this value is inside the dialog click handler, then fetch it there so you are getting the latest value:

```
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            var CatChk = $("#chkCatActive").val() ? 1 : 0;
            var CategoryName = $("#txtCategoryName").val(); 
            var CatDDL = document.getElementById("ddlCategoryParent3");
            var ParentID = CatDDL.options[CatDDL.selectedIndex].value;               
            window.alert(PageMethods.saveCat(categoryName, ParentID, CategoryID, CatChk));

        }
```

Comment: Good explanation, I figured it had something to do with how I was fetching the value. I ended up dropping the variable and putting $("#txtCategoryName").val() into the click function as a parameter passed through to my page method.  I also added validation to make sure there is text.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you're attempting to get the value right as soon as the page loads, before the input field gets filled out. Place this code inside the button click function:

```
var CategoryName = document.getElementById('txtCategoryName').value;
```

and it should work for you. If not, let us know.

> **Your code should look something like this:**

```
       click: function () {
            // note: CategoryID not used yet.
            var CategoryName = $("#txtCategoryName").val();
            var CatChk = $("#chkCatActive").val();
            var CatDDL = document.getElementById("ddlCategoryParent3")
            var ParentID = CatDDL.options[CatDDL.selectedIndex].value;
            if (CatChk) { CatChk = 1; } else { CatChk = 0; }
            $(this).dialog("close");
            window.alert(PageMethods.saveCat(CategoryName, ParentID, CategoryID, CatChk));
        }
```

Comment: They aren't trying to fetch the value before the element is created.  The element is in the HTML of the page and their code was in `document.ready()` so the element exists just fine.  The issue is that they are getting the value BEFORE it has been edited so the value they fetch is not the value that the user edits it to be.  Your solution will work, but your explanation for why the problem occurs is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, I thought those DOM elements were only created when .dialog() was called.